# Create a Shared Codebase For Web And Mobile in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, web

I'm building an app where I need to handle files. I mostly develop mobile apps so I need to import only `dart:io`.
But, for my new project, I also need to add web platform. If I import `dart:io` in mobile or `dart:html` on web, it cannot compile.
Rest of my app is ready to work on both Web and Mobile, I only need to handle `dart:io` and `dart:html`.